# Apex Else IF statement failing

Tags: apex

So when you consider the following two else if statements. First Statement should have triggered as the conditions met; which is lead Source was 'PPL' and Campaign Name did not contain in the set(**Campname**), my second else if is the last else if I have within the IF statement which is executing even though my first else if is True. Am I using wrong syntax for **does not contain** ?

```
else if((l.LeadSource=='PPC' || l.LeadSource=='PPL') && !            (Campname.contains(l.Campaign_Name__c))) //CampName is a set
{
    ids3.add(l.id);
}

else if()
{
    l.No_match_for_immediate_response__c= true;
}
```

Comment: why do you have a blank else if(), why not just have else {  l.No_match_for_immediate_response__c= true;}

Comment: There is a [containsIgnoreCase](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_containsIgnoreCase) that you might use if the case is inconsistent or you don't care about it in your logic.

Comment: Is it possible to provide the debug log? I would be interested to know what the values are in the Campname set and what l.Campaign_Name__c equals.

Comment: @Rao: I actually removed the logic; since its irrelevant to this.

Comment: @Keith: Will try to use that thanks ! and is there any syntax issue that you notice in the current logic ?

Comment: @techbusinessman: sure, I can but I can't send it right away I will do it once I get off from work. If that's fine.

Comment: @techbusinessman: Well thanks to the Debug ! Campaign Name is getting updated by a team where there is a delay at times and so at that point the debug returns Campaign Name as 'Null'. So I included null in the set I'm checking the values from and it worked !! Thanks techbusinessman .

Comment: Debug logs for the win!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well thanks to the Debug !

Campaign Name is getting updated by a team where there is a delay at times and my scheduler class is calling the logic before any Name is provided to Campaign, so at that point the debug returns Campaign Name as 'Null'.

So I included **null** in the set I'm checking the values from and it worked !!